# Stop loop on progressbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working with this progressbar:
https://codepen.io/thegamehasnoname/pen/JewZrm

The problem I have is it loops and what I want to achieve is:

- stop on last progress slide (**stop loop**).
- if the user is on **last** progressbar slide **after** it has stopped and I click on a `.button-prev` button it should start from the previous slide, not the first slide of the progressbar.

here is the code:

```
// swiper custom progressbar
const progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
const progress = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.progress'));
const status = document.querySelector('.status');

const playNext = (e) => {
  const current = e && e.target;
  let next;

  if (current) {
    const currentIndex = progress.indexOf(current);
    if (currentIndex < progress.length) {
      next = progress[currentIndex+1];
    }
    current.classList.remove('active');
    current.classList.add('passed');
  }

  if (!next) {
    progress.map((el) => {
      el.classList.remove('active');
      el.classList.remove('passed');
    })
    next = progress[0];
  }
  next.classList.add('active');
}

progress.map(el => el.addEventListener("animationend", playNext, false));

playNext();
```

I tried adding this:

```
if (current) {
   if (!next) {
     $('.progress-container div').addClass('passed');
   }
}
```

But the class `passed` gets deleted and the progressbar starts again.

This is the js of the `previous button` I have:

```
$(document).on('click', ".button-prev", function() {
  $('.progress-container div.active').prev().removeClass('passed').addClass('active');
  $('.progress-container div.active').next().removeClass('active');
});
```

any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have the fix ! Simply add a return statement to avoid to set the active calss to the first progress element.

```js
if (current) {
    const currentIndex = progress.indexOf(current);
    if (currentIndex < progress.length) {
      next = progress[currentIndex+1];
    }
    current.classList.remove('active');
    current.classList.add('passed');
    
    if (!next) {
     $('.progress-container div').addClass('passed');
      return;
   }
  }
```